# P in constant declaration

Tags: java

In `java.lang.Double`, there are the following constant declarations:

```
public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023;
public static final double MIN_NORMAL = 0x1.0p-1022;
```

What is the `P` for? Is the difference in case important?

I am aware of the `L`, `D` and `F` used for `Long`s, `Double`s and `Float`s, but have never seen a `P` before.

Comment: A hexadecimal float, perhaps?

Comment: "p" for "power" (?) as "e" could be misunderstood as an hexadecimal symbol (?)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `P` (or `p`) indicates a hexadecimal [floating-point literal](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.2), where the significand is specified in hex.

The `p` is used instead of the `e`. The `d` and `f` suffixes that you've seen are orthogonal to this: both `0x1.0p+2f` and `0x1.0p+2d` are valid literals (one is of type `float` and the other is of type `double`).

At first glance it might seem that the `0x` prefix is sufficient to identify a hex floating-point literal, so why have the Java designers chosen to change the letter from `e` to `p`? This has to do with `e` being a valid hex digit, so keeping it would give rise to parsing ambiguity. Consider:

```
0x1e+2
```

Is that a hex `double` or the sum of two integers, `0x1e` and `2`? When we change `e` to `p`, the ambiguity is resolved:

```
0x1p+2
```

Answer (score 5):

The `p` syntax if used for defining a double literal in hex.  This is useful when you want to define its exact representation but isn't useful in general code because you want the double to be a decimal value rather than some hex pattern.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hexadecimal floating-point literal, and the syntax is: sign**0x**significand**p**exponent. See this [blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/hexadecimal_floating_point_literals) for an explanation.

Comment: Joe Darcy's blog post is a good read. Unfortunately it has been removed from its original location. It can still be accessed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318174923/http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/hexadecimal_floating_point_literals), though.

Answer (score 2):

It's used to signify a hexadecimal floating point literal.

> A floating-point literal has the following parts: a whole-number part,
>   a decimal or hexadecimal point (represented by an ASCII period
>   character), a fractional part, an exponent, and a type suffix. A
>   floating point number may be written either as a decimal value or as a
>   hexadecimal value. For decimal literals, the exponent, if present, is
>   indicated by the ASCII letter e or E followed by an optionally signed
>   integer. **For hexadecimal literals, the exponent is always required and
>   is indicated by the ASCII letter p or P followed by an optionally
>   signed integer.**

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#230798