# 0xp0 prints 0.0 (Hexadecimal Floating Point Literal)

Tags: java

I just wonder why this compiles? and what does it mean since it does compile?

```
System.out.println(0xp0); // p?
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0.0
```

Comment: For me this does not compile, with `javac 1.7.0_02`. Only `0x0p0` does.

Comment: @TheGuyOfDoom I am using `1.7.0_05`.

Comment: I'm by the way on the Sun JDK. that might be relevant.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603232/p-in-constant-declaration  (I found the answers here to be clearer to the layman)

Comment: Have a looking in the `Double` class for examples like `public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023;` and `public static final double MIN_NORMAL = 0x1.0p-1022;`

Comment: I get compile error: `error: hexadecimal numbers must contain at least one hexadecimal digit`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a floating point hex literal.

> For hexadecimal floating-point literals, at least one digit is required (in either the whole number or the fraction part), and the exponent is mandatory, and the float type suffix is optional. The exponent is indicated by the ASCII letter p or P followed by an optionally signed integer.

See the specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Answer (score 11):

[The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) explains it:

```
HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral:
    HexSignificand BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffixopt

HexSignificand:
    HexNumeral
    HexNumeral .
    0 x HexDigitsopt . HexDigits
    0 X HexDigitsopt . HexDigits

BinaryExponent:
    BinaryExponentIndicator SignedInteger

BinaryExponentIndicator:one of
    p P
```

Based on the above, I would expect a mandatory `.HexDigit` before the `p`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is how to manually convert the following to a decimal number:

```
double hfpl = 0x1e.18p4;
System.out.println(hfpl); // 481.5
```

[image]