# Why can this floating point text value be parsed as a double?

Tags: java, try-catch, numberformatexception

Does anybody know why the following snippet does not throw a `NumberFormatException`?

```
public class FlIndeed { 

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println(new FlIndeed().parseFloat("0xabcP2f"));
   }

   public float parseFloat(String s) { 

      float f = 0.0f;
      try { 
         f = Float.valueOf(s).floatValue();
         return f;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
         System.out.println("Invalid input " + s); 
      }
      finally {
         System.out.println("It's time to get some rest");
         return f; 
      }  
   }
}
```

Note that there is a P inside `.parseFloat("0xabcP2f"));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it do accept hexadecimal values and you are passing a valid hexadecimal value.

From [**Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) (s = input String argument)

> s should constitute a FloatValue as described by the lexical syntax
>   rules:
>
> ```
>     FloatValue:
>         Signopt NaN 
>         Signopt Infinity 
>         Signopt FloatingPointLiteral 
>         Signopt HexFloatingPointLiteral 
>         SignedInteger 
>
>     HexFloatingPointLiteral:
>         HexSignificand BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffixopt 
>
>     HexSignificand:
>         HexNumeral 
>         HexNumeral . 
>         0x HexDigitsopt . HexDigits 
>         0X HexDigitsopt . HexDigits 
>
>     BinaryExponent:
>         BinaryExponentIndicator SignedInteger 
>
>     BinaryExponentIndicator:
>         p 
>         P
> ```

about `NumberFormatException` thrown from `valueOf`

> where Sign, FloatingPointLiteral, HexNumeral, HexDigits, SignedInteger
>   and FloatTypeSuffix are as defined in the lexical structure sections
>   of the of the Java Language Specification. If s does not have the form
>   of a FloatValue, then a NumberFormatException is thrown.

About use of p in hex: [P in constant declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603232/p-in-constant-declaration)

Answer (score 3):

```
 System.out.println(new FlIndeed().parseFloat("0xabcP2f"));
```

The 0xabcP2f is a HexSignificand value which is legal for Float.valueOf("0xabcP2f").
So it's not throws any exception

For details Please have look on this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html

> If m is a float value with a normalized representation, substrings are used to represent the significand and exponent fields. The significand is represented by the characters "0x1." followed by a lowercase hexadecimal representation of the rest of the significand as a fraction. Trailing zeros in the hexadecimal representation are removed unless all the digits are zero, in which case a single zero is used. **Next, the exponent is represented by "p" followed by a decimal string of the unbiased exponent** as if produced by a call to Integer.toString on the exponent value.

So it's used to signify the exponent in the hexadecimal string which you entered, it's a perfectly legal part of the hex string so there's no parsing error and no `NumberFormatException` thrown.